# How to start Cassandra service in a particular port?

Tags: sockets, terminal, cassandra, homebrew

HI I want to start Cassandra in port 9042 however when I run the command

```
brew services start cassandra22
```

it starts Cassandra but not on port 9042.
Is there a way to get it to run on default port 9042? Also not sure on how to check on which port it is running exactly

Answer (score 1):

9042 is the native transport port and is set with the `native_transport_port` in `cassandra.yaml`.

So:

```
native_transport_port: 9043
```

will change it to port `9043`.

The location of `cassandra.yaml` is rather dependent on how you installed cassandra but is nominally in the `resources/cassandra/conf` folder.